# Finding all injective and surjective functions that satisfy $f(x+f(y))=f(x+y)+1$.

Tags: calculus, functions

How to find all injective and surjective functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy $f(x+f(y))=f(x+y)+1$?

By setting $x=0$, I get that $f(f(y))=f(y)+1$, so if $z=f(y)$, then $f(z)=z+1$. I can see that this function injective and surjective. But how do I prove that there are no other possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already shown: if $f(x+f(y))=f(x+y)+1$ and if $f$ is surjective, then $f(z)=z+1$ for all $z$.

Now it remains to show that the function given by $f(x)=x+1$ , is injective and surjective and satiesfies $f(x+f(y))=f(x+y)+1$.

But this is easy.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Fred, assuming surjectivity of $f$ is enough to conclude that any solution is of the form $f(x) = x+1$.

Interestingly, you can only assume injectivity of $f$ and still get the same ansswer. Indeed, since $f$ is injective and $ f(x+f(y)) = f(x+y) + 1 = f(y+f(x))$, we have

$$ x + f(y) = y + f(x).$$

So plugging $y = 0$ gives $f(x) = x + f(0)$. Then replacing $x$ by $x+f(y)$ then gives

$$f(x+y) + 1 = x + f(y) + f(0),$$

Plugging $x = y = 0$ proves that $f(0) = 1$, so $f(x) = x+1$ as expected.